# Check before taking from a Java BlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency

The problem I have is something like a single producer multiple consumer problem. Except the consumer are "different" and I need a way of "peek"ing on the new item (to check who its for) before taking it.

*The problem is actually a single server thread that serves multiple client threads. Client will request info, then server should reply to this client*

How can I do that? A possibility is a loop like:

```
while (true) {
    if (q.peek() ... check here ...) {
        // do something
    } else {
        Sleep(...); // prevent taking up too much CPU?
    }
}
```

But doesn't seem ideal/right?

Comment: Rather than having to peek, how about establish different queue for each message type, hence you can associate corresponding consumer to each queue.

Comment: server thread is producer, and multiple client threads is multiple consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

Option 1. Have one consumer of the queue that takes items off and delegates them to the "real" consumers. This one will require a lot of work on your part, because your main consumer will have to know which of the "real" consumers are busy. In addition, if one of the "real" consumers takes more resources than the others, it has the potential to block the queue while the main consumer waits to hand off the message.

The better solution is:

Option 2. Use one queue for each type of consumer. Your producer will determine which queue each message type belongs to and drop it into the correct queue. Then each consumer will pull from the queue it's interested.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make the following operations atomic, by synchronizing them in a single block.

```
// Make sure queue is final. If not, use a final Object monitor.
synchronized(queue) {
    queue.peek
    queue.pool
}
```

This is to ensure after your consumer thread discover the queue contains the right targeted message (through `BlockingQueue.peek`), it can consume the message (through `BlockingQueue.pool`)

Still, your solution is not ideal. You are implementing a technique named `busy pooling`, which can waste a lot of CPU resource. You do not take advantage of `BlockingQueue.pool`. `BlockingQueue.pool` will put your consumer threads in wait stage, till the data is available.

To take full advantage of `BlockingQueue.pool`, each consumer threads should hold their very own queue. So that they can just call `pool` without having to perform busy `peek`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better not to use BlockingQueue at all:

```
public class Synchronizer {
    Object obj;

    synchronized void put(Object obj) throws InterruptedException {
        this.obj = obj;
        notifyAll();
        while(obj != null) {
            wait();
        }
    }

    synchronized Object take() throws InterruptedException {
        for(;;) {
            wait();
            if (obj instanceof MyObject) {
                notifyAll();
                Object tmp = obj;
                obj = null;
                return tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

though there may be a version of a Synchronzer that consumes from a BlockingQueue

Comment: Why roll your own?  This seems like a tremendously bad practice given that there is a battle tested version supplied by the JRE.